# Если замазать рекламу на сайте

Tags: реклама, google-adwords, яндекс-директ

Представим что я поставил рекламу от яндекса или гугла на свой сайт.

Поверх рекламного блока я поставлю непрозрачный фон, чтобы сделать рекламу невидимой.

Получается - реклама есть, а пользователь её не видит. Ну и будет ли мне яндекс/гугл платить за показ рекламы? Если нет, то как они определят эту хитрость?

Comment: Чтобы платили за показ рекламы, сайт должен быть настолько охрененный и с такой посещаемостью, что подобными мелкими пакостями ему заниматься ни к чему :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На сколько я знаю, яндекс и google, не платят за показа рекламы, они платят только за переходы по рекламным ссылкам...

Comment: Про яндекс не знаю, а google платит за каждые 1000 показов. Мелочь конечно, но платит.